# How to write flv from h264 frame byte data?

Tags: c#, video, encoding, h.264, flv

I've got a capture card that captures `HDMI` source, the `SDK` of this card support a function that will return a pointer to `H.264` frame **pbFrame** and frame_info **pbFrameInfo**.

The `SDK` support only `MP4` files, but the recorded file is very important and it is not allowed to lose it in any situation so I need `FLV` instead of `MP4`.

So is there any way to store `FLV` File using the `H.264` frame and frame_info

**More Info:**

- Resolution  = 1920 x 1080
- Frame duration = 381000
- This is a snapshot of frame and frame_info converted to hex, frame
  not complete because of it huge to paste here :

**Frame 1**

frame_info `01000000cccccccc718401000000000071840100000000000000000000000000`

frame `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` .... etc

**Frame 2**

frame_info `00000000cccccccc0c770100000000000c770100000000000000000000000000`

frame `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` .... etc

**Frame 3**

frame_info `00000000ccccccccd691010000000000d6910100000000000000000000000000`

frame `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` ... etc

**Edit**

- I've written a *row* file that contains the frames as is arrived you
  can see the file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gi3ddgm5wuf4pn2/raw.h264?dl=0)
- An FLV file that created from the raw file above [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8drvud8bs1ewjqf/raw_h264.flv?dl=0)
- A 2 sec MP4 file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pv66bddoii9xsul/%5BVideo%20%2800-0%20Pro%20Capture%20Quad%20HDMI%29%5D2017_9_19___17_27_40.mp4?dl=0).

Comment: `.flv` and `.mp4` files have completely different encoding. You need to **convert** the file, not use its data to re-write it. Consider using a tool like ffmpeg.

Comment: I've got a live streaming of HDMI not a pre-recorded file. this is the callback Method `public static void H264EncoderCallback(IntPtr pbFrame, int cbFrame, IntPtr pbFrameInfo, int cbFrameInfo, IntPtr pvParam)
        { byte[] ptr = new byte[cbFrame];
            Marshal.Copy(pbFrame, ptr, 0, cbFrame);
                     Console.WriteLine(XICapture.ByteArrayToString(ptr));
                     byte[] ptr2 = new byte[cbFrameInfo];
            Marshal.Copy(pbFrameInfo, ptr2, 0, cbFrameInfo);
                     Console.WriteLine(XICapture.ByteArrayToString(ptr2));}`

Comment: @KobyDouek I have an `H.264` Frame not an `MP4` File .

Comment: It's not clear to me why do you think that FLV is better than MP4. These are just containers for encoded streams.

Comment: @dymanoid because if my process terminated in an unusual way the `MP4` file will corrupt and won't be readable, but `FLV` is readable at any time while recording either process finished will or terminated.

Comment: Hasn't Flash just offically been declared dead?

Comment: @TaW Any other alternative that may not corrupt if the process ended in an unusual way ??

Comment: @BlackRoot you are correct. FLV is a good solution for your situation. Those frames don’t like like h.264 to me however.

Comment: @TaW It is Flash (_the browser plugin_) that is declared dead. Asker is talking about a Flash video (_an a/v media container_).

Comment: @BlackRoot what exactly is problem? Also what format is your H264?.. I suggest you either show full (testable) bytes of a keyframe bytes (and we need the SPS and PPS too for MPEG decoder setup)... Or record one short MP4 and use a tool like `FFmpeg` to **transcode** (remux, not convert) from MP4 to FLV. Find your H264 bytes in the FLV, to see what bytes goes where, and create your own FLV by code in similar fashion. Read FLV specifications PDF too (eg :some metadata values are of type _Double_  (8 bytes) not as _Integer_ type so they might seem like strange amounts at first).

Comment: @szatmary sorry to be late in response but I have returned from a weekend, whatever you say that doesn't like h.264 frame but the SDK provide me this function and pass the frame throw it `public static void H264EncoderCallback(IntPtr pbFrame, int cbFrame, IntPtr pbFrameInfo, int cbFrameInfo, IntPtr pvParam){}` where pbFrame is the frame as I mentioned in my question, so what is the format you mean should my frame look like to be an H.264 Frame (if you can post an example)??   note that this frame is not complete I've just posted a piece of the frame head.

Comment: @VC.One sorry to be late in response but I have returned from a weekend, whatever, as I read during the war with encoding and media files, is the SPS is the bytes that follow the first `00 00 01` or `00 00 00 01` and PPS is the next one after second delimiter `00 00 01` is that what you mention ?? also how do I (remux not convert) I can't find a FFMpeg command for that ??

Comment: @VC.One as I got from the card support team the frame is AVCC format.

Comment: @BlackRoot I just noticed the _small_ edit (now with link). **(1)** Your above posted (incomplete) first frame bytes does not have SPS or PPS. I suspect the SDK generates a half-empty MP4 shell first with metadata like the SPS/PPS then later proceeds (per frame received) to update same metadata with additional info like the bytes offset & byte size of this current frame _X_ etc. **(2)** I will try decode your frame when **link permission** is granted. If possible add an MP4 link too (just 2 or 3 secs) to extract the PPS / SPS / SEI from it, otherwise can still try "estimating" it without MP4.

Comment: @VC.One I will post the raw new link with FLV file that converted from the raw and a 2 sec mp4 file. **(1)** in my post I just put the head of the frame and a frame information from the SDK. about your suspicion, the raw file is readable and convertible.I'm very thankful for your concern.

Comment: @BlackRoot have seen links. Will advise soon. Also your FLV has Sorenson codec not H264 odec. If used FFmpeg then type `ffmpeg -i raw.h264 -c:v copy output.mp4` to transfer h264 into FLV (should be fast since "direct copy" instead of re-encode). So you want advice to achieve same FLV/h264 as FFmpeg by your own code without using FFmpeg, right?

Comment: @VC.One exactly that what I want. Also to be informed this FLV created via an online website, not FFMPEG.

Comment: @VC.One I've read raw.h264 file with _H264videoESViewer_ after that I discovered that I've mistaken with frames arrange, so I re-arranged it in my question, whatever the file contains **SPS**,**PPS**, and **SEI** and all elements should be in h264 frames see this image https://www.dropbox.com/s/uolmrsgi0o5ptzj/U1.png?dl=0 ,, so can you help me how to read SPS and PPS data and write all information in FLV file ??

Comment: @BlackRoot is this solved or you still need a solution?

Comment: @VC.One it's very close to solved but still need a solution, now I've stopped in parsing _SPS_, _PPS_, and other `NALU's` and how to write it in `FLV`.